# Plot device ON/OFF data in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, pivot-chart

I have following data containing

- a device
- a timestamp of when the deviced logged the event
- an event: ON or OFF

[image: Device data]

I would like to get a graph that shows per day the duration a device was active <sub>(duration = OFF timestamp - ON timestamp)</sub>

[image: Duration graph]

I can't figure out how to do this *without* manually creating a new table from my inputs like this

[image: Device duration]

---

Raw testdata **Edited**

```
device  timestamp   action
frig1   21/07/2022 10:30    ON
frig2   21/07/2022 10:32    ON
frig2   21/07/2022 10:35    OFF
frig1   21/07/2022 10:38    OFF
frig1   22/07/2022 10:30    ON
frig1   22/07/2022 10:37    OFF
frig2   22/07/2022 11:30    ON
frig2   22/07/2022 11:35    OFF
frig2   22/07/2022 11:59    ON
frig2   22/07/2022 12:06    OFF
```

Comment: Without an additional computation of the duration I do not see how this can fly. But is your issue that you do not want to create a table or is it the manual procedure of creating it?

Comment: @karl - My issue is mainly the manual procedure of creating it. If I can create the second table and have it synced with the source table (adding items on the fly), that would do too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your table is called 'raw':

[image]

Select any cell in the table and Use Data>Get & Transform Data>From Table/Range.

This will open the Power Query Editor with your new query:

[image]

Change the data types of "timestamp" to 'Date' and "action" to 'time' by clicking the icon in the top-left of the column header.

Select the 'State' column by clicking the column header.

Use Transform>Pivot column and configure it like this:

[image]

You should now have one row per device/date:

[image]

Use Add Column>Custom Column> and configure it like this:

[image]

Change the data type of the elapsed_time column to 'Duration'.

You should now have this:

[image]

Use Home>Close & Load To and select your preferred option. Either put the data into a worksheet or directly to a pivot table or pivot chart.

When you need to refresh this query, you just use Data>Refresh All or Ctrl+Alt+F5 or, if you've put the data into a worksheet, right-click the query result and select 'Refresh':

[image]

Comment: This.is.awesome! I only had to make minor adjustment because I actually start with 3 columns io the 4 you used but at least, that *is* something I could handle myself. Thank you very much.

Comment: I already know I'm going to come back to this answer so many times you should be getting royalties for it.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I see what happened now. I pasted your data into my spreadsheet and used text to columns. I guess it should've been timestamp with a date/time and action should be ON/OFF. Oh well, I guess the gist of the answer is still OK :)

Comment: my sample data contained just one ON/OFF per device per day. My actual data contains multiple ON/OFF per device per day. Do you happen to know how I can adjust for that? I have added a sample to the raw testdata to better show my intent.

Comment: @FlexYourdate - figured it out (perhaps convoluted but it works). 1. Change type to decimal number io time. 2. Aggregate with sum. 3. Add new column [OFF] - [ON]. 4. Change type to time.